# What is the correct way to use ECDSA in Crypto++

Tags: c++, crypto++, ecdsa

When I verify a signature using ECDSA verifier in Crypto++, if the public key is incorrect the method just crash the application. Should I try catch the exception? What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the "crash" is because you have a flaw in your code? The "best way" to handle any crash really depend on the crash and what you're doing, any we don't know anything about that. So please create a [mcve] of what you're doing to show us. And please take some time to refresh about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... should I try catch the exception? What is the best way to handle this?

It depends on how you want to do it. I think there are three options.

The information below is from [Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) and [SignatureVerificationFilter](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SignatureVerificationFilter) on the Crypto++ wiki.

First, you can catch the `SignatureVerificationFailed` exception if you like:

```cpp
try
{
    DSA::Verifier verifier(publicKey);
    StringSource ss2(message+signature, true,
        new SignatureVerificationFilter(
            verifier, NULL, THROW_EXCEPTION
            /* SIGNATURE_AT_END */
       )
    );

    std::cout << "Verified signature on message" << std::endl;
}
catch (SignatureVerificationFailed& ex)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to verify signature on message" << std::endl;
}
```

Second, you can get the result as a boolean value. Notice lack of `THROW_EXCEPTION`:

```cpp
bool result = false;
StringSource ss(message+signature, true,
    new SignatureVerificationFilter(
        verifier,
        new ArraySink(
            (byte*)&result, sizeof(result)),
        PUT_RESULT | SIGNATURE_AT_END
   )
);

if(result)
    std::cout << "Verified signature on message" << std::endl;
else
    std::cerr << "Failed to verify signature on message" << std::endl;
```

Third, you can forgo pipelines and just call `VerifyMessage` on the `Verifier` object:

```cpp
bool result = verifier.VerifyMessage(ConstBytePtr(message), BytePtrSize(message), ConstBytePtr(signature), BytePtrSize(signature));
if(result)
    std::cout << "Verified signature on message" << std::endl;
else
    std::cerr << "Failed to verify signature on message" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was testing with incorrect public key, then exception was thrown. So we should try catch for this situation? Thanks!